# Override magento admin file

Tags: magento2.3

Hi i want to override magento admin file below are the details.

```
Name space: Magento\User\Block\Role\Tab;

File name: Info.php

Class name: class Info extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
```

i want to override below function

```
protected function _initForm()
```

How to achieve this ??

Comment: This will work for you https://magenticians.com/magento-2-override-block/

Answer (score 0):

You can define  in di.xml in your custom module:

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magento 2 preference to override this type of method.
Please follow the steps:
Create a custom module and define preference in that custom module in di.xml file

```
<preference for="Magento\User\Block\Role\Tab\Info" type="Custom\Module\Block\Role\Tab\Info" />
```

Now create bock info.php file in your module, extend Magento\User\Block\Role\Tab\Info and override the method

```
protected function _initForm() {
// you logic
}
```

Please run setup:upgrade comment before verifying this feature.

I hope this will help you.